# How to debug Infopath 2010 web form?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, infopath

Well, in visual studio 2008 we were able to create infopath 2007 web form project and after that attach to iis process to debug infopath web form.

In visual studio 2010 there is not infopath project and we can use only vsto and cant attach to iis process.

So, how to debug Infopath 2010 web form? - is it possible?

Answer (score 5):

Debugging in InfoPath2010 is a bit tricky.You need to configure your VSTO Advanced Build option to store debug info and then open using VS2010.Attach the w3wp.exe processes using VS2010.Then you should be able to debug.For a complete steps ,check out my blog post  [How to debug Infopath2010 using VS2010](http://ybbest.wordpress.com/2011/01/09/how-to-debug-infopath2010-using-vs2010/)

Answer (score 1):

The process for debugging InfoPath 2010 form templates with code behind has changed quite a bit from InfoPath 2007 thanks to Microsoft not letting us develop our stuff in Visual Studio anymore :-)

Actually there is a really nice MSDN article about [Investigating Issues with InfoPath 2010 SharePoint Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg271285.aspx#IP14_Debugging) which will surely help you!

There are several things you need to do to enable your forms for debugging (all done in the InfoPath code editor or Visual Studio Tools for Applications):

1. Build in Debug mode (Project Properties > Build > Active (Debug)
2. Enable full Debug Info (Project Properties > Build > Advanced)
3. Clear "Enable Just My Code" and select "Suppress JIT..." (Tools > Options > Debugging)

Then you can deploy your template and attach to either the correct `w3wp` process or the `SPUCWorkerProcess` for a sandboxed solution - for this you will need to use Visual Studio.

In any case: Make sure you read the MSDN article ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. Debugging in Infopath would need the following steps [highlighted in this post](http://nikspatel.wordpress.com/2011/07/)

In a nutshell it would require for you to:

- Configure VSTA settings
- Republish the Infopath form
- Deploy the Infopath form
- Debug the code through Visual Studio (not VSTA)