# Browser-Enabled InfoPath form doesn't open in web-browser

Tags: sharepoint-2010, infopath2010

I am using SP2010.

I am having **.xsn** file and its just simple with one field.
I have already set VSTA project & code for this form. I have not written any thing in C# code for VSTA its just simple.
I do design check and publishing to a document library, its successfully done. my InfoPath forms's security level is "automatically determine...."

My issues are below:

1. But when i open my custom document library and and try to add any item New Form is not opening in browser. this just opens in InfoPath design form. how i can open it in web browser.?
2. How i am going to debug this code created in VSTA project ?.

Answer (score 0):

in reply:

1. check file/form option/compatibility/form type is Web Browser Form. or you can remove code behind of infopath template.
2. for debugging VSTA project see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7610105/1071194)

Comment: if you want, send your template file to me and i check it.

Comment: hi Amir .. thnx for reply....actually I have to add code in VSTA editor and  when i add code in template and republish that ... it shows me "The Form template has been published to ser but it can be only opened in InfoPath filler. sandboxed solution ... ...  " that long mesage error.... so i am puzzled wat to do now ? ....

Comment: i guess you must use designer checker that show you warnings of Infopath form.

Comment: you know that form library differ by form list?
on form list you can't use code behind for web-browser enabled form!

Comment: no rules added and no data sources as well.. ...its just simple one contorl with datepicker form that's it...nothing more...